# UIViewController as a popup

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

I have ViewController inside static lib.
Also have public interface to

- presentPopup:
- presentInNavigationVC:(UINavigation...)

Is it possible to show my ViewController as popup in other viewController and what is the best way to do it? 
I suppose that I have to add my viewController view as subView to other ViewController view.
But it should be complete logic to switch between popup mode and pushing my viewController into navigationController.

Popup should looks like FBDialog:

[image: Facebook popup]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the view size of that view controller,and add it in the parentviewcontroller using addsubview method`[[self view] addSubview:bar];`.when your process is over then use remove from superview method to delete that view lke this `[presentingController.view removeFromSuperview];`.